# How can I convert os.path.getctime()?

Tags: python, os.path

How can I convert `os.path.getctime()`  to the right time?

My source code is:

```
import os

print("My Path: "+os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir("."))
print("Root/: ",os.listdir("/"))


for items in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(items):
        print(items+" "+"Is a Directory")
        print("---Information:")
        print("    *Full Name: ",os.path.dirname(items))
        print("    *Created Time: ",os.path.getctime(items))
        print("    *Modified Time: ",os.path.getmtime(items))
        print("    *Size: ",os.path.getsize(items))
    else:
        print(items+" Is a File")
```

Output:

```
---Information:
    *Full Name:  
    *Created Time:  1382189138.4196026
    *Modified Time:  1382378167.9465308
    *Size:  4096
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; Can you clarify what you mean by the right time?

Answer (score 112):

I assume that by *right time* you mean converting timestamp to something with more meaning to humans. If that is the case then this should work:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1382189138.4196026).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2013-10-19 16:25:38'
```

Comment: Depending your use case, you might want to replace complex .strftime(...) by simplier .isoformat() and gain ms information

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the same problem, and resolv indirectly it with the help of answers. So a solution :

```
import os
import time
import datetime

# FILE_IN a file...

file_date = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(FILE_IN))
file_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(file_date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
print("Last modif: %s" % file_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

With this solution :
a date object with the good value, an example of conversion to see it (with the good string format to insert in a mysql database).

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for. It can be modified to something like "20221214".

Answer (score 5):

You can also use **ctime** function from the **time** module.

```
import os
import time

c_time = os.path.getctime(r'C:\test.txt')
print(c_time)
print(time.ctime(c_time))
```

Output:

```
1598597900.008945
Fri Aug 28 09:58:20 2020
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

> The return value is a number giving the number of seconds since the epoch  (see the `time` module)

And in the [`time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#module-time) module we see [`localtime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime)

> Use the following functions to convert between time representations:
>
> ...
>
> | seconds since the epoch | `struct_time` in local time | `localtime()` |

And from there use [`strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to get the format you want

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.fromtimestamp(path.getatime("/Users"))
    datetime.date(2015, 3, 10)
```